# Why are these 2 python class instance could equal to each other?

Tags: python, equality, python-dataclasses, python-class

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class ThreeDPoint:
    x: int | float
    y = 0.0
    z: int | float = 0.0

point_1 = ThreeDPoint(1.0,2)

point_3 = ThreeDPoint(1,2)
print(point_1 == point_3)
```

The result is true.

I ran it in python playground. The result said it is true. I think this dataclass module might play some magic trick inside but I am not sure what is exactly happening.

Comment: What makes you think they shouldn't be equal? What does `1.0 == 1` give you?

Comment: The designers of Python decided that integer `1` is equal to float `1.0`.

Comment: Also, why is this question tagged with python 2.7?  Dataclasses certainly did not exist back then...

Comment: The other issue is that `dataclass` overrides the `==` operation, and compares instances by comparing the attributes (similar to the way dictionaries are compared).

Comment: @JohnGordon: Not to mention the designers of basically every language above the assembly level. (Save extremely type-strict languages like Rust, which simply forbid the comparison)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic trick. In Python, integer 1 and float 1.0 are the same

```
> 1 == 1.0
True
```

On the other hand, type(1) is not the same as type(1.0)

```
> type(1) == type(1.0)
False
```

If you would like the equality operator to behave the way you suggested (= returning False when x has the same value but different type), then you could define your own equality method for the class, like so:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class ThreeDPoint:
    x: int | float
    y = 0.0
    z: int | float = 0.0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        for var, var_value in self.__dict__.items():
            try:
                other_var_value = getattr(other, var)
                if not (var_value == other_var_value and type(var_value) is type(other_var_value)):
                    return False
            except AttributeError:
                return False
        return True


point_1 = ThreeDPoint(1.0, 2)
point_3 = ThreeDPoint(1, 2)
print(point_1 == point_3)
```

Comment: Hmm, you don't need to iterate over the other dictionary to define "found", you just try to grab the attribute and handle a KeyError. `other_var_value = getattr(other, var)`.

Comment: Simpler and faster without the loop (and properly using `is`/`is not` for the type comparison): [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVKxasMwEIWO-orrZkFqnGQpAUOHUuhSOmQXIj4lBltypXOoS_-kS5b2o_o1lWXHsQ3pDeJ0797TO3FfP1VDB6NPp--a1N39781eWVNCJknuCukcOsjLyli6lBh7uOThhO3BIj6-mlzThoGP9w34HD5BFUZSKDWQQhInIf-YwD0QkAwVCIFvQkQOC7UAQwe0vFNtI1egDUHucu1I6h1GoWMx9jBqb8Mi1VbDi6HnsiqwRE2YDR3KWDhKL-APcZRFjd5be3HBAY9zwtJFM83wqLhQUtgjSSJ7tuMhPmF449RUGA0c7ocIs4TyTJBDZ6uXv03nL07tjMZ8koVDNitubY2Msar9HbH0bke_FS3jZAEr3qOra6htb4NCCn37mbee8_5jrXm3b_3andfvDw)

Comment: You are right guys @ShadowRanger, Guimoute, I wrote it very fast without testing or checking it much. Edited the answer. Thx

Comment: @JosefJoeSamanek: If you want `AttributeError` to be raised for you to handle, get rid of the third argument to `getattr` (which is returned *instead* of raising an `AttributeError`, and could be mistaken for the correct value if any of the attributes could legally take a value of `False`).

Comment: Thx, fixed (leftover from previous version)

Answer (score 0):

1.0 equals to 1 in python, so `1.0 == 1` will return true.
Just like Barmar said, when you compare dataclasses you are comparing instances using their attributes, so

`1.0 == 1` is true.

`2 == 2` is true

Therefore, `ThreeDPoint(1.0,2) == ThreeDPoint(1,2)` is true.

Comment: thank you, I am a beginner of learning python. I thought one is int another is float and point_1 or 3 return a class containing different type of numbers so I consider this might not equal and I was confused of it. now all cleared, thanks